# N-array of monitored old lead acid batteries with solar panels

Tags: batteries, solar-cell, control

I would like to build a system of a arbitrary number of old and different specs. lead acid batteries (recycled) working with a solar regulator (mppt or pwm, doesn't matter).

The initial idea was to put all batteries isolates with a schottky diodes for charge and for load, all the time.

The second idea is use a thyristor rather than a diode: lower drop voltage and you can cut if the battery is out of parameters: volt, amps, aH over total or temp (monitoring with a small plc).

The third idea is the same as second, but the charger is not from a common regulator, it is a individual charger per battery: 3 steps regulator for this kind of batteries (bulk, charge and float).

Any better idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know which idea is a _good_ idea, but idea #3 sounds like a bad one if the individual chargers all are MPPT chargers. Changes to the current drawn from the solar array by any one of them will affect the voltage that is seen by all of them. I don't know how that will affect the MPPT algorithm, but it doesn't sound promising.

Comment: Well, the idea #3 is use a work battery for the mppt regulator from solar panels, and this battery supply a system with some 3-stages charges for the array of batteries. I think it is little complicated, but a ideal for the rest of batteries of the system. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Thyristor drops MORE voltage than Schottky. || MOSFET can be far lower drop than Schottky but V is not usually an issue. || Lowest V battery will hog current with simple paralelling. This can be good and bad depending on how wide the difference in battery states and sizes are. || A small series R per battery can promote current sharing. Vpanel is usually greater enough than Vbat that you can tolerate a volt or two drop. 
Good could be a max current source per battery. Needs say MOSFER and 1/4 of quad opamp per battery. When batteries load panel above PV Imax little is lost in droppers.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!
Well, I have tried a test circuit, and with the IRF1010e (it is MOSFET), the drop is very low (about 0,2V at 12V,1A), but it is not important now.
The key of the design, I think is what you say, a regulation of the intensity in function of the capacity of the battery, for a proportional work of all the batteries present at the system.

Comment: The way I think is to use a low voltage BUS common (12v, any battery will be over 12v always o it is disconnect of the circuit) and a dispositive to go down V each battery. But I can not know how equalize the intensity.

Comment: I think the approach is the "ORing", I need to know about it. 
Thanks!